# Merging into a self referential table with identity columns

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a number of records I need to add/update in a table that represents a hierarchical tree structure. The table has three columns

```
Id(PK, IDENTITY, int) | Description(varchar(50)) | ParentId(FK(Id), nullable, int)
```

A null value in the ParentId indicates the root node of a tree. 
If possible, I'd like to insert/update these records in a single operation but since the identity isn't assigned until a record is inserted I'm having trouble figuring out how to capture this so child nodes' ParentId can be populated.

So given an existing table:

```
Id | Description | ParentId
1  | 'Foo'       | NULL
2  | 'Bar'       | 1
3  | 'Fizz'      | 1
4  | 'Buzz'      | 3
```

Is it even possible to insert a new root node and it's child nodes in a single operation?

I've attempted combining `MERGE` with `UPDATE` but it's either not possible to reference the columns of `INSERTED` in the same operation that populates them or else I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: What format would the data to be inserted be in? Would it defeat the purpose to load that into a temporary table with the same structure as the destination table?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a single operation, but a loop that will run `n` number of times where `n` is the number of levels in your staging hierarchy.

This uses recursive [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to build the hierarchy path for both a given target table (`tree`) and a given staging table (`staging`). The first example uses views containing the recursive code, and the second uses inline ctes if views are not an option.

This solution requires that the entire ancestor path be in the staging table (i.e. from the root node up), and that the combination of `parentid,description` is unique for each table.

The full code is available in the demos, but here is the recursive cte view for the `staging` table:

```
create view dbo.staging_path as 
with cte as (
  select id, description, parentid
      , path = convert(varchar(512),description)
      , parent_path = convert(varchar(512),null) 
  from dbo.staging t
  where t.ParentId is null
  union all
  select c.id, c.description, c.parentid
      , path = convert(varchar(512),p.path+'|'+c.description)
      , parent_path = convert(varchar(512),isnull(p.parent_path+'|','')+p.description)
  from dbo.staging c
    inner join cte p
      on c.parentid = p.id
  )
select id, description, parentid, path, parent_path
from cte;
```

which returns:

```
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+-------------+
| id | description | parentid |     path      | parent_path |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | Foo         | null     | Foo           | null        |
|  2 | Bar         | 1        | Foo|Bar       | Foo         |
|  3 | Fizz        | 1        | Foo|Fizz      | Foo         |
|  4 | Buzz        | 3        | Foo|Fizz|Buzz | Foo|Fizz    |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

---

[dbfiddle.uk with two recursive views](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3a2ee6f1fa7845f9db91499836aff307)

```
declare @rc int = 1;

while @rc > 0
begin;
  insert into tree (description, parentid)
    select sp.description, parentid=tp.id
    from dbo.staging_path sp
      left join dbo.tree_path tp
        on sp.parent_path = tp.path
    where not exists (
      select 1
      from dbo.tree_path i
      where sp.path = i.path
      )
      and (tp.id is not null or sp.parentid is null);

  set @rc = @@rowcount;
end;
```

---

If you can not create views to simplify the code as above, you can use inline recursive ctes like so:

[dbfiddle.uk without views](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7cfd522545903926af3a0173aadf19c7)

```
declare @rc int = 1;

while @rc > 0
  begin;
    with tree_path as (
      select id, description, parentid
          , path = convert(varchar(512),description)
      from dbo.tree t
      where t.ParentId is null
      union all
      select c.id, c.description, c.parentid
          , path = convert(varchar(512),p.path+'|'+c.description)
      from dbo.tree c
        inner join tree_path p
          on c.parentid = p.id
    )
    , staging_path as (
      select id, description, parentid
          , path = convert(varchar(512),description)
          , parent_path = convert(varchar(512),null)
      from dbo.staging t
      where t.ParentId is null
      union all
      select c.id, c.description, c.parentid
          , path = convert(varchar(512),p.path+'|'+c.description)
          , parent_path = convert(varchar(512),isnull(p.parent_path+'|','')+p.description)
      from dbo.staging c
        inner join staging_path p
          on c.parentid = p.id
      )
    insert into tree (description, parentid)
    select sp.description, parentid=tp.id
    from staging_path sp
      left join tree_path tp
        on sp.parent_path = tp.path
    where not exists (
      select 1
      from tree_path i
      where sp.path = i.path
      )
      and (tp.id is not null or sp.parentid is null);

    set @rc = @@rowcount;
  end;
```

---

[dbfiddle.uk with recursive view for target table, inline cte for staging](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cd008f35601619a5e64b8ea12ba5baf2)

Each option results in `tree` having the following rows (`identity` was set to start at 41 for this table to differentiate the id from staging):

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| Id | Description | ParentId |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 41 | Foo         | null     |
| 42 | Bar         | 41       |
| 43 | Fizz        | 41       |
| 44 | Buzz        | 43       |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to all be in one insert statement you could do it by setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON, manually filling in that field during the insert, and then turning it back off again.

It should then pick up where you left off:

> If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for
>   the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the
>   current identity value

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql

Comment: If you're doing this while the system is live, and others may also be trying to insert rows, you can use `IDENT_CURRENT` to get the current setting for the identity column, then use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` to move the next identity value, so the next one assigned will be leave a gap the size of your record set. Then, you set the ID columns for your new rows to the values in that gap.